# is there any way to define httpheaders in single class,interface or annotation in java?

Tags: java, spring

is there any way to define httpheaders in single class in java? It is something like creating a wrapper class for userdefined httpHeaders used in my application. instead of defining all headers in my controller method.

```
@PostMapping
public <ResponseEntity<Book>> getBooks(
   @ModelAttribute("requestContext") RequestContext context, @PathVariable("bookId") String bookId,
   @RequestHeader(value="x-institute-id") String instituteId,
   @RequestHeader(value="x-customer-last-logged-time") String xCustomerLastLoggedTime,
   @RequestHeader(value="x-customer-ip-address") String xCustomerIpAddress,
   @RequestHeader(value="x-interaction-id", required=false) String xInteractionId){

     ---implementation

   }
```

So that It can be interface or annotations. Like:

```
public class MyApplicationHeaders{
   @RequestHeader(value="x-institute-id") String instituteId,
   @RequestHeader(value="x-customer-last-logged-time") String xCustomerLastLoggedTime,
   @RequestHeader(value="x-customer-ip-address") String xCustomerIpAddress,
   @RequestHeader(value="x-interaction-id", required=false) String xInteractionId)
}
```

So that we can use it as :

```
@PostMapping
public <ResponseEntity<Book>> getBooks(
   @ModelAttribute("requestContext") RequestContext context, @PathVariable("bookId") String bookId, @MyApplicationHeaders appHeaders{

     ---implementation

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs of [`@RequestHeader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html)

> If the method parameter is `Map<String, String>`, `MultiValueMap<String, String>`, or `HttpHeaders` then the map is populated with all header names and values.

This means you can use either a `Map` or `HttpHeaders` as a parameter type to hold multiple header values. In your case, `Map` is applicable since you are working on non-standard headers:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Book> getBooks(
    @ModelAttribute("requestContext") RequestContext requestContext,
    @PathVariable("bookId") String bookId,
    @HttpHeaders Map<String, String> appHeaders) {

    String instituteId = appHeaders.get("x-institute-id");
    // do something else
}
```